# how to fire a sql trigger whenever the password change

Tags: sql-server

I have a table containing id, user_Name and password. I want to create the trigger which will fire when ever the password changes.

Suppose the table is:

```
create table reg
(
    id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    userName varchar(100),
    pass varchar(100)
)
```

and I want to save `userName, password, changeDate` in to below table

```
create table regBackUp
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    regId foreign key references reg(id),
    oldPass varchar(100),
    changeDate date
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to create `after update` trigger on `reg` table.

In that trigger you need to write to table `regBackUp` records selected from table named `deleted`.
 It is special table available in that triggers and it will hold values of `reg` table just before update.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) for reference about syntax of `create trigger` expression.

Answer (score 0):

Use this. [TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

You can get the old values from `DELETED` table

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgTest ON regFOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF UPDATE(pass)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @id AS INT
        DECLARE @pass AS varchar(100)

        SELECT @id = ID, @pass = pass FROM DELETED

        INSERT INTO regBackUp (regId, oldPass, changeDate) 
              VALUES (@id, @pass, GETDATE())
    END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `After Update Trigger` with [**Update()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187326.aspx) function to find out whether column is updated or not. From docs.

> indicates whether an INSERT or UPDATE attempt was made on a specified
>   column of a table or view. UPDATE() is used anywhere inside the body
>   of a Transact-SQL INSERT or UPDATE trigger to test whether the trigger
>   should execute certain actions.

Create a `After Update trigger` like this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER reg_pass_trg
ON reg
after UPDATE
AS
  BEGIN
      IF UPDATE(pass) --Works only when pass is mentioned in update statement
        INSERT INTO regBackUp
                    (regId,oldPass,changeDate)
        SELECT ID,pass,Getdate()
        FROM   deleted
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO namepassback 
            (username, 
             pass, 
             [date]) 
SELECT username, 
       pass, 
       Getdate() 
FROM   namepass 
WHERE  id = 1
```

use above query that will work same without creating trigger

Comment: This "solution" it totally unrelated to your question. For example, it always selects record with `id=1` - and doesn't checks was it updated or not.

Comment: Your answer doesn't make any sense at all where are you checking whether `pass` column is **updated** or not and always `Id=1`